# Auto-scrolling of parent doesn't work when child elements put into a separate component

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to add more features to my chat app. And now I try to implement auto-scrolling to the bottom of chat window when new messages appear on that window. And this piece of code works as expected:

```
<script>
// some other code
let isScrolledUpByUser;

function onScrollHandler(event) {
  const { target } = event;

  if (!target) {
    return;
  }

  const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, offsetHeight } = target;
  isScrolledUpByUser = scrollTop !== scrollHeight - offsetHeight;
}

function scrollToBottom(node, _) {
  return {
    update() {
      if (!isScrolledUpByUser) {
        node.scroll({ top: node.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    },
  };
}
</script>

<div
  class="wrapper"
  use:scrollToBottom={[$messages, $isTyping]}
  on:scroll={onScrollHandler}
>
  {#if $messages.length > 0}
    {#each messages as message, index (message.id)}
      <Message {message} />
    {/each}
  {:else}
    <div>sorry, no messages yet</div>
  {/if}

  {#if $isTyping}
    <div>user is typing...</div>
  {/if}
</div>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
</style>
```

But I'd like to put the logic of displaying messages to a separate Messages component because the current component (Chat window) already has pretty much code.

```
<script>
// same javascript code
</script>

<div
  class="wrapper"
  use:scrollToBottom={[$messages, $isTyping]}
  on:scroll={onScrollHandler}
>
  <Messages {$messages} />

  {#if $isTyping}
    <div>user is typing...</div>
  {/if}
</div>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  /* same styles */
</style>
```

And the messages component:

```
<script>
  import Message from "../messageBubbles/Message.svelte";

  export let messages;

</script>

{#if messages.length > 0}
  {#each messages as message, index (message.id)}
    <Message {message} />
  {/each}
{:else}
  <div>sorry, no messages yet</div>
{/if}
```

But now the parent component does not autoscrolls itself when getting new messages. But I noticed that if I get rid of this condition in onScrollHandler function:

```
      if (!isScrolledUpByUser) {
        node.scroll({ top: node.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
      }
```

autoscroll will work just fine. But then I can't check if user scrolled up.
I have no idea how to fix this.